# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed on javasql exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i am creating simple rest api using jersey and here i assigned all the data fetched from database to variables and then return those variables data as list but i get an error. i have seen other examples but i don't get it whats wrong here is what i did:

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{
public List<User> readUser() {
    List<User> list = new ArrayList();
    User u = new User();
    try {
    System.out.println("inside readuser impl");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user");
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            u.setId(id);
            u.setName(name);
            u.setAddress(address);
            System.out.println(u);
            list.add(u); //adding user object to list
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return list; //returning to list for json response
 }
}
```

and here is my controller that gives json response after getting object

```
@Path("/rest")
public class UserController {

@GET
@Path("/getall")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> getAllUser(){
    UserDAO udao = new UserDAOImpl();

    return udao.readUser();
 }

}
```

Comment: Don't call `con.close()` inside `while` loop, since closing the connection also closes the statement and the resultset. *Highly recommend* you start using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on `Connection`, `Statement`, *and* `ResultSet`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `Class.forName()` has not been necessary any more for ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the connection after one iteration which will cause *Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed on javasql exception* at the second iteration, move the con.close outside the loop

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{
 public List<User> readUser() {
   List<User> list = new ArrayList();
   User u = new User();
   try {
        System.out.println("inside readuser impl");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = 
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb", "root", "");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user");
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                u.setId(id);
                u.setName(name);
                u.setAddress(address);
                System.out.println(u);
                list.add(u); //adding user object to list
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        con.close();
        return list; //returning to list for json response
     }
    }
```

or even you can use try with resource it will close all resource automatically

```
 public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{
    public List<User> readUser() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList();
        User u = new User();
        try( Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb", "root", ""); 
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user");){
        System.out.println("inside readuser impl");
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                u.setId(id);
                u.setName(name);
                u.setAddress(address);
                System.out.println(u);
                list.add(u); //adding user object to list
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return list; //returning to list for json response
        }
     }
```

i didn't test the second one due i don't have the environment in this machine

Comment: *Second example:* Calling `Class.forName` *after* `DriverManager.getConnection`? Really? --- Also, code is badly formatted.

Comment: Ohh, i didn't see it thank you for noticing me i told you i don't have the environment in this machine

Comment: @Andreas ` class.forname` is not necessary anyway